# Android/Node.js - String '@' in Android App becomes '%40' in Node.js

Tags: java, android, node.js

I am developing an android app which is connected to Node.js.

I've got some data in ARTICLE table and it includes 'user_email'.
I am trying to get all the articles posted by the current user who logged in.

[image]

And this is the result of getting 'member_email' by 'Query'

[image]

As you can see, '@' becomes'%40'. I guess it is because of 'Query'. It comes properly when it is 'Body'. But I want to use 'Query' and I need to get all the data:

`where user_member = fman1335@gmail.com`

with the received data like this:

`member_email; fman1335%40gmail.com`

Since I only receive the string with '%40' instead of '@', The SQL can't find `fman1335@gmail.com'. So, I need to change '%40' to '@'.

I can change only '%40' part to '@' in the string variable. However, I'd like to know if there's any better way to change this problem technically. For example, encoding or decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is `%40` URL encoded.

You could use [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/decodeURI)

```
var uri = 'https://mozilla.org/?x=шеллы';
var encoded = encodeURI(uri);
console.log(encoded);
// expected output: "https://mozilla.org/?x=%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8B"

try {
  console.log(decodeURI(encoded));
  // expected output: "https://mozilla.org/?x=шеллы"
} catch(e) { // catches a malformed URI
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful. However, Could you please tell me how I can improve this question? I got -2...

Comment: You're not really explaining your issue, and I had more or less to guess it. You could explain what you tried, and add the stacktrace of your buggy line. In general, be more precise :)